# Permanently inject environemt variable from jenkins using EnvInject plugin

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, client

I know how to inject environment variables using the envinject plugin. However, after each job run, they are cleared from the client system, which makes sense.

I would like to know if there is a way to set environment variables permanently on a jenkins client?